# Raphaeljs animation kills my browser

Tags: animation, resources, raphael, transform, cpu

I have this code where I have a made a character using 20 paths and put it into a set. 
Now when I animate the set, the first transformation runs smoothly, the second animation stutters, the third animation doesn't happen as it should and the 4th animation kills my pc, the browser hangs and in the task manager I can see that it consumes up to 70% of CPU. How can I avoid this and free the resources so all the animations run smoothly.

*I have to execute 10 simple y-axis transformation animations on that character.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvD4c/2/)

```
window.onload = function(){  
var paper = Raphael(0,0,400,400);

    var character = paper.set();
    paper.setStart();
    var attr = {fill:'red',stroke:'none'};  

    var shape = paper.rect(100,100,10,20).attr(attr);
    var shape = paper.rect(100,100,10,20).attr(attr);
    var shape = paper.rect(100,100,10,20).attr(attr);
    var shape = paper.rect(100,100,10,20).attr(attr);
    var shape = paper.rect(100,100,10,20).attr(attr);
    var shape = paper.rect(100,100,10,20).attr(attr);
    var shape = paper.rect(100,100,10,20).attr(attr);
    var shape = paper.rect(100,100,10,20).attr(attr);
    var shape = paper.rect(100,100,10,20).attr(attr);
    var shape = paper.rect(100,100,10,20).attr(attr);
    var shape = paper.rect(100,100,10,20).attr(attr);
    var shape = paper.rect(100,100,10,20).attr(attr);
    var shape = paper.rect(100,100,10,20).attr(attr);
    var shape = paper.rect(100,100,10,20).attr(attr);
    var shape = paper.rect(100,100,10,20).attr(attr);
    var shape = paper.rect(100,100,10,20).attr(attr);
    var shape = paper.rect(100,100,10,20).attr(attr);
    var shape = paper.rect(100,100,10,20).attr(attr);
    var shape = paper.rect(100,100,10,20).attr(attr);
    var shape = paper.rect(100,100,10,20).attr(attr);

    var character = paper.setFinish();
    character.transform("t0,200")



    //1st animation..
    var chartrnsfrm = Raphael.animation({
        transform:'...t0,-48'        
    },1000,"easeout",function(){
        character.animate(chartrnsfrm1.delay(2000))
    });
    character.animate(chartrnsfrm.delay(2000));


    //2nd animation..
    var chartrnsfrm1 = Raphael.animation({
        transform:'...t0,-48'        
    },1000,"easeout",function(){
        character.animate(chartrnsfrm2.delay(2000))
    });


    //3rd animation..
    var chartrnsfrm2 = Raphael.animation({
        transform:'...t0,-48'        
    },1000,"easeout",function(){
        character.animate(chartrnsfrm3.delay(2000))
    });


    //4th animation..
    var chartrnsfrm3 = Raphael.animation({
        transform:'...t0,-48'        
    },1000,"easeout");
}
```

Comment: quite strange... does that happen if you use `setTimeout()` instead of `animation.delay()`?

Comment: Here "[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvD4c/7/)" I tried using setTimeout() but still not working well. Did I do it correctly?

Comment: Hmm... That doesn't seem to help. How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/rvD4c/13/

Comment: The question why the chain animation fails is still valid, of course.

Comment: variable shape is declared 20 times, you need to avoid that.

Comment: I did that to just give an idea that I have that many number of shapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are expecting the callbacks from animation to work differently than they actually do.

The variable `character` holds a set of paths. Raphaël does not currently map those to groups that would animate all children at once. What is going on here is that each path is animated seperately. In effect, each such animation is triggering a callback when it is done. That way, for the first animation, `chartrnsfrm1`, the callback is triggered 20 times. You therefore schedule the second animation, `chartrnsfrm2`, for the whole character 20 times. By the time you reach `chartrnsfrm3`, your callback is being triggered 20^3 = 8000 times. Scheduling those animations is what kills your browser.

What I have done is remember the last shape, and only schedule the animation of the whole character if the element that the current callback is being called for (`this`) is equal to the `lastShape`.

```
var lastShape = shape;

//1st animation.. 
var chartrnsfrm = Raphael.animation({
    transform:'...t0,-48'        
},1000,"easeout",function(){
    if (lastShape == this)
        character.animate(chartrnsfrm1.delay(2000))
});
character.animate(chartrnsfrm.delay(2000));
```

You can see the whole updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rvD4c/14/), it has the fourth animation enabled and all of them run smoothly.

Comment: The documentation does not state this explicitly enough, even I didn't know about this before I started debugging. I will try to get the documentation updated. While my fiddle is not an ideal implementation, it was the easiest way to fix the code that was provided. Ideally, you wouldn't be using all those callbacks in the first place, and schedule your animations from some place else. Also: I do not know whether the scheduling is killing your browser, or rather the animations running concurrently. I didn't bother to check, because both should be avoided.